# Issue within my custom Class module - Lua

Tags: class, lua, subclass

I'm currently working on a module that allows JS-Like classes to be implemented easily in Lua

I've added the ability to extend classes but I'm having an issue with extending classes twice, it seems to be some sort of issue within the super constructor function that's causing a recursive call however I can't seem to figure out where the bug is coming from, any help would be appreciated

Module:

```lua
local ClassCreator = {}
ClassCreator.extends = {__extends = true}

local function modifyFnEnv(f, env)
    local fEnv = getfenv(f)
    for i,v in pairs(env) do fEnv[i] = v end
    setfenv(f, fEnv)
end

local ClassMt = {
    __call = function (self, ...)
        local newClass = {}
        setmetatable(newClass, {__index = self.prototype})
        modifyFnEnv(newClass.constructor, {
            self = newClass
        })
        newClass.constructor(...)
        return newClass
    end
}

local function makeClass(self, targs)
    local Class = {
        prototype = {}
    }
    setmetatable(Class, ClassMt)
    local constructor, SuperClass = function() end, Class

    for i,v in pairs(targs) do
        if i == ClassCreator.extends then
            SuperClass = v
            setmetatable(Class.prototype, {__index = SuperClass.prototype})
        elseif i == "constructor" then 
            constructor = v
        else
            Class.prototype[i] = v 
        end
    end
    if SuperClass ~= Class then
        modifyFnEnv(constructor, {
            super = SuperClass.prototype.constructor
        })
    end

    Class.prototype.constructor = constructor
    return Class
end

setmetatable(ClassCreator, {
    __call = makeClass
})



return ClassCreator
```

Test Code:

```lua
local Class = require("Class")
local Human = Class {
    constructor = function(name, age)
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    end,
    
    describe = function(self)
        return string.format(
            "My name is %s and I am %d years old",
            self.name,
            self.age
        )
    end
}

local Programmer = Class {
    [Class.extends] = Human,
    constructor = function (name, age, yearsOfExperience)
        super(name, age)
        self.yearsOfExperience = yearsOfExperience
    end,

    describe = function(self)
        return string.format(
            "My name is %s and I am %d years old, I have %d years of experience",
            self.name,
            self.age,
            self.yearsOfExperience
        )
    end
}

local LuaProgrammer = Class {
    [Class.extends] = Programmer,
    constructor = function (name, age, yearsOfExperience)
        super(name, age, yearsOfExperience)
    end,

    describe = function(self)
        return string.format(
            "My name is %s and I am %d years old, I have %d years of experience in Lua",
            self.name,
            self.age,
            self.yearsOfExperience
        )
    end
}

local John = Human("John", 35)
local JohnProgrammer = Programmer("John", 35, 5)
local JohnLuaProgrammer = LuaProgrammer("John", 35, 5)

print(John:describe())
print(JohnProgrammer:describe())
print(JohnLuaProgrammer:describe())
```

Expected output:

```
My name is John and I am 35 years old
My name is John and I am 35 years old, I have 5 years of experience
My name is John and I am 35 years old, I have 5 years of experience in Lua
```

Current output:

```
lua: src/test.lua:20: stack overflow
stack traceback:
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        ...
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'super'
        src/test.lua:20: in function 'constructor'
        ./src/Class.lua:17: in function 'Programmer'
        src/test.lua:51: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that `Programmer.constructor` recurses infinitely through the call to `super`. That is, `super` is `Programmer.constructor` but should be `Human.constructor`.

The reason for this is simple: You're messing with function environments (fenv) assuming `getfenv` to return a different environment for each function. This isn't the case though: By default all functions have the same environment, the global environment `_G`. You're thus constantly writing to the global environment, overriding previous `self` and `super` global variables.

If you fix this, you get a second error since every constructor creates its own table - but only if the metatable is called! Thus when you call `super`, bypassing the metatable, the function environment still uses the old `self` instance, overwriting the instance variables.

**In general, I'd advise against messing with function environments. It's often bad both for performance and readability. This is another case of messing with function environments gone horribly wrong.**

If you really want this as a nice hack to show off Lua's metaprogramming capabilities, this is how I'd rewrite `modifyFnEnv`:

```lua
local function modifyFnEnv(f, env)
    setfenv(f, setmetatable(env, {__index = getfenv(f)}))
end
```

The metatable with `__index` set allows accessing the previous function environment, but `env` takes precedence. Note: If this is called multiply times on the same function, it will grow the index chain each time; you'll probably rather want to replace the function environment.

You don't need the `__extends` key in the `Class.extends` table; Lua tables are compared by reference, not by value. You can thus move the key checks out of the loop to improve performance.

Here's the fixed `Class.lua`:

```lua
local ClassCreator = {}
ClassCreator.extends = {}

local function modifyFnEnv(f, env)
    setfenv(f, setmetatable(env, {__index = getfenv(f)}))
end

local ClassMt = {
    __call = function(self, ...)
        local newInstance = {}
        setmetatable(newInstance, {__index = self.prototype})
        getfenv(newInstance.constructor).self = newInstance -- set self
        newInstance.constructor(...)
        return newInstance
    end
}

local function makeClass(self, targs)
    local Class = {
        prototype = {}
    }
    setmetatable(Class, ClassMt)

    local constructor = targs.constructor or function() end
    local constructorEnv = {}
    modifyFnEnv(constructor, constructorEnv)

    local SuperClass = targs[ClassCreator.extends]
    if SuperClass then
        setmetatable(Class.prototype, {__index = SuperClass.prototype})
        function constructorEnv.super(...)
            local super = SuperClass.prototype.constructor
            getfenv(super).self = constructorEnv.self
            super(...)
        end
    end

    -- Copy prototype
    for k, v in pairs(targs) do
        Class.prototype[k] = v
    end
    -- Remove special non-method fields
    Class.prototype[ClassCreator.extends] = nil
    Class.prototype.constructor = nil

    Class.prototype.constructor = constructor
    return Class
end

setmetatable(ClassCreator, {
    __call = makeClass
})

return ClassCreator
```

Note that I'm changing the constructor function environment exactly *once* and only modifying it afterwards, e.g. by setting `self` or `super` fields.

`test.lua` is fine as-is. Output as expected:

```
$ lua5.1 test.lua
My name is John and I am 35 years old
My name is John and I am 35 years old, I have 5 years of experience
My name is John and I am 35 years old, I have 5 years of experience in Lua
```

**Let me repeat: Don't do this in production code.**